# XSLT Deduplicate across nested elements

Tags: xslt, xsd

I have XSD schema that I use as a source to generate a XSLT that reorders elements in a XML file according to the schema (basically, using XSLT to generate XSLT from XSD). I need to deduplicate elements that are present multiple times within xs:choice elements (that can also be nested) in the XSD.

My XML features a lot of optional fields so I've grouped them up using choice as some of them appear together. And choice is the source of the problem as some elements are repeating inside choice elements and bubbling up to the resulting XSLT template.

**EDIT:** I've tried to use multiple passes by saving complexType in a variable. But I don't know how to make identity transform on specific namespace.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://test.example.com/xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="__Schema">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="ref"/>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="schema"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="type"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="description"/>
          <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="allOf"/>
            <xs:element ref="__Property"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="type"/>
          <xs:element ref="__Items"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element ref="pattern"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="enum"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="schema" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="ref" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="allOf" substitutionGroup="oneOf"/>
  <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="__Property" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="enum" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="__Items" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="oneOf" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="pattern" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

My template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xslt:stylesheet version="2.0"
                 xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias">
    <xslt:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xslt:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="xt" result-prefix="xslt" />
    <xslt:template match="*[@name and @substitutionGroup]"/>
    <xslt:template match="xs:element[@name and not(@substitutionGroup) and not(@group)]">
        <xslt:element name="xslt:template">
            <xslt:attribute name="match">
                <xslt:value-of select="string-join(@name|../xs:element[@substitutionGroup=current()/@name]/@name, '|')"/>
            </xslt:attribute>
            <xslt:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xslt:element>
    </xslt:template>
    <xslt:template match="xs:element[@ref]">
        <xslt:element name="xslt:apply-templates">
            <xslt:attribute name="select">
                <xslt:value-of select="@ref"/>
            </xslt:attribute>
        </xslt:element>
    </xslt:template>
    <xslt:template match="xs:group[@ref]">
        <xslt:apply-templates select="//*[@name=current()/@ref]/*"/>
    </xslt:template>
    <xslt:template match="xs:group[@name]"/>
    <xslt:template match="xs:choice|xs:sequence|xs:complexType">
        <xslt:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xslt:template>
    <xslt:template match="xs:schema">
        <xt:stylesheet version="2.0">
            <xt:output method="text" indent="no"/>
            <xslt:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xt:stylesheet>
    </xslt:template>
</xslt:stylesheet>
```

currently, the result is as following:

```
<xslt:template match="__Schema">
      <xslt:apply-templates select="ref"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="schema"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="type"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="description"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="allOf"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="__Property"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="type"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="__Items"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="pattern"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="enum"/>
   </xslt:template>
```

I need the second `select="type"` to disappear wile preserving order of all other elements. I don't want to create a pipeline.

Comment: I think that what you are attempting is very challenging, but I worry that you've jumped into coding without having a clear understanding of the algorithms you need to develop. Certainly you're asking us for help as if this were a coding problem rather than a design problem. For starters, any code like this that takes raw XSD as input is likely to be making simplifying assumptions about what you can find in a schema: for example, you appear to be ignoring xs:include and target namespaces.

Comment: If you use XSLT to generate XSLT then please show us a minimal sample that does that, otherwise it is hard to tell what is going on. Also which version of XSLT do you use?

Comment: @MichaelKay I can live with assumptions right now. I will look into those issues later, when they become relevant. I want to apply the resulting XSLT on human input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that sample if you add

```
<xslt:key name="choice-ref" match="xs:choice//xs:element[@ref]" use="@ref"/>

<xslt:template match="xs:choice//xs:element[@ref][not(. is key('choice-ref', @ref, ancestor::xs:choice[1])[1])]" priority="10"/>
```

you get

```
   <xslt:template match="__Schema">
      <xslt:apply-templates select="ref"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="schema"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="type"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="description"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="allOf"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="__Property"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="__Items"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="pattern"/>
      <xslt:apply-templates select="enum"/>
   </xslt:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQgr

As Michael Kay pointed out in a comment, processing XSD schemas in general is a rather complex task, so take the above as a simple example meant to address that particular problem you have shown in the sample input/output.

Comment: Well, this doesn't work when I add another complexType, I need the keys to be "local" to a particular complexType.

Comment: I tried to have some "scope" in there using the third argument of the `key` function in the expression `<xslt:template match="xs:choice//xs:element[@ref][not(. is key('choice-ref', @ref, ancestor::xs:choice)[1])]"/>`, it might be better to use `<xslt:template match="xs:choice//xs:element[@ref][not(. is key('choice-ref', @ref, ancestor::xs:choice[1])[1])]"/>` or as you talk about a complex type to walk up to `<xslt:template match="xs:choice//xs:element[@ref][not(. is key('choice-ref', @ref, ancestor::xs:complexType[1])[1])]"/>`.

Comment: Not sure whether that helps, the schema language is that complex and allows that many variations and nestings that it is hard to process.

Comment: Okay, got it! I got spooked by ambiguous rule match warning. Added priority and all is well.